# Is there any interest in doing a community wide charity event?

Tags: discussion, charity

First off, **this is not something that has been discussed with StackExchange**. This is a community thing that has no official backing at this point.

Would there be any interest from members of the community to run/participate in a charity event for [Child's Play](http://www.childsplaycharity.org/)? If there is interest, I would probably take the same approach as the meetup and plan it in parts via meta questions. I am willing to help facilitate, coordinate, run, organize, whatever, but I wanted to see if there is community interest in doing something first.

Comment: Do you have a specific charity event in mind?

Comment: @badp No specific event in mind at the moment. Deciding that would be the next step. A lot of people to marathons, some people do tournaments... there are lots of possibilities

Comment: I would instead more ask that Arqade give some spotlight to SDA's [Aweseome Games Done Quick](http://marathon.speeddemosarchive.com/), starting tomorrow. Maybe that's just me, though.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh Getting Arqade members to participate or donate to other causes is great, but this post is about interest in organizing our own version. I'd recommend making an ad, and posting that in our [community ads post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/community-promotion-ads-2013) so that it can get some attention for our users.

Comment: It may be hard to get much support *without* something specific in mind.

Comment: Maybe for a real charity. Children being bored in hospitals doesn't even register with me as an issue compared to the actual problems in the world.

Comment: Looks funny =) xD

Comment: @kotekzot - There are other causes out there, but bringing joy to children in pain is a real charity.

Comment: @kotekzot - Your statement strikes me as glib and extremely rude. What universal moral scale would you like to measure what qualifies as an "actual" problem? Certainly fighting things like poverty or disease are important. But is it not worthwhile to bring a little bit of happiness to some small child somewhere who's dying slowly and painfully in a hospital? Or the thousands who are just in pain, and scared of doctors and tests they don't understand?

Comment: @sjohnston it's a question of allocating limited resources among competing claims. How many starving children's lives is one willing to sacrifice in order to entertain children in 1st world country hospitals? Entertainment is fundamentally unimportant compared to saving people from starvation, disease or lack of drinkable water. And let's not forget that these children already have other avenues of entertainment - reading, for example, is infinitely cheaper and just as fun.

Comment: Child's Play is an extremely well-respected organization in the gaming community, with a hugely positive history of doing good (http://www.childsplaycharity.org/testimonials).  But the most important thing is that good is done (http://www.all-creatures.org/stories/starfish.html).  @kotekzot - What organization would you prefer to support?

Comment: @kotekzot I chose Child's Play because it is very related to gaming and gaming culture. A lot of people within the gaming community are very passionate about this topic. If this event goes well, we can certainly consider doing more in the future, and different charities can be chosen.

Comment: @MatthewRead I wanted the community to help decide on the event, partially because I felt more involvement from everyone might make it more successful, but also because I didn't necessarily have any ideas that stood at as good for us to do as an online community. Though I do like MBraedley's idea at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With +10, I will assume we have interest from the community to do something. I'll mark this as accepted and create a question about what we should. Here are the rough next steps for planning:

- [What type of event are we going to run?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5741/15643) 
   **Top Tag Marathon**
- How are we going to run it, and what are the details?

  - [Will it be online or in person?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6837/15643) 
     **Online**
  - [What will donations count towards?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/when-people-donate-for-our-marathon-what-will-they-donate-towards/6843#6843) 
     **Goals in each game**
  - [What games will we play from our top tag list? And what will the goals be for each game?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6863/15643) 
     **Minecraft, Portal 2, Terraria, and Borderlands 2**. *Team Fortress 2* may be an extra stream event if we can get enough people for a game.
  - [What should our marathon goals be?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6898/what-should-our-marathon-goals-be)
- When will we run it?
- [Who will participate/help run?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6900/15643)

I'm sure there may be more or less as we go, but this is a rough outline of how I'll approach it.

Answer (score 4):

We could do a weekend live stream consisting of the [top tags](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/90978/top-all-time-tags) on the site.

So for instance, a group of us could start a fresh Minecraft world and after a certain goal, kill the ender dragon.  For ME3, goals could be for certain missions.  A similar option could exist for Skyrim and D3.  I'm not a LoL or SC2 player, so I don't know what to suggest for that.

It would be similar to the various Child's Play marathons, notably (AFAIK) Zeldathon.  Members would switch off streaming duties at scheduled points.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a video game, one charity event that would quite easy to pull together would be create a dungeon and sell spots for both good and bad then have a couple of nerd famous people run through them. People would pay X dollars to place a creature, or magic item, or helpful item, or whatever. Set it up in tiers like a kickstarter and have certain things happen when we reach funding goals.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by a dungeon...

Comment: as like dungeons and dragons... although this being video games, maybe we do it in neverwinter knights or one of the other dm-able fantasy games. My friends and I did it old school graph paper style, but that was while present at a con so everybody was there at the time.