# Should our Marathon be online or in person?

Tags: discussion, charity

We're going to do a [Top Tag Marathon](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6815/15643) for our [charity event](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5731/15643). Should we run it online, or in person in a central location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Online

Vote for this option if you want to run it online. The idea would be we would have set people swap in and out of the stream and certain times. People would marathon through a game, or for a certain amount of time, and then hand it off to the next person to marathon. This makes it easier for us to do as an online community and allows more people to participate in the actual marathoning.

### Challenges

- Everyone would need to be set up with a stream, and we would need to figure out how to transfer the stream from one person to another
- Online might get less money since it can basically be only marathoning at normal gaming hours, making this no different than just playing every other day
- We'll need fallback strategies if people can't make it to their set time

Comment: "Normal gaming hours" is pretty flexible though when you take into account timezone differences, especially between the US and Europe, both places that we have several active members.

Answer (score 2):

## In Person

Vote for this option to run it as an in person marathon. The idea would be to pick a centralized location for as many users as possible and run a marathon at someone's place. The stream would run for a weekend from one location, and as many users as could show up would participate. With an in person marathon, we can also do a bit more things since there will be more than one person there streaming, and we can follow formats from other charity marathons.

### Challenges

- Finding a centralized location with enough people to marathon might be tough
- Someone would need to volunteer their place so that we could run the stream
- We need to make sure we have all of the games from the top tag list, as well as all the systems they need to be run on

Comment: +1 here for my vote :)

Comment: For reference: [here](https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?msid=213689790075558322917.0004c60f50fcc5f857c9d&msa=0&ll=49.862776,-96.9104&spn=1.581051,4.22699) is a link to a map of Arqade members... feel free to add yourself. It's pretty obvious that there's nowhere to group with enough people nearby unless there are many willing to travel quite a bit.