# When people donate for our marathon, what will they donate towards?

Tags: discussion, charity

Since we've decided on a [Top Tag Marathon](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6815/15643) for our [charity event](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5731/is-there-any-interest-in-doing-a-community-wide-charity-event), what will people be donating for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What our goals will be in each game

Similar to how Mario Marathon does it, we can set a set of goals for each of the games, and the more people donate, the more goals we complete. We can either combine this with the per game voting, or just go top to bottom as Mario Marathon does.

Comment: I'd be up for doing a Minecraft marathon with others, with a goal of defeating the Wither in one play session, or some other ridiculous goal.

Comment: just an idea for a diablo 3 marathon.  Groups of 4 people create new characters on hardcore on mp3 (or some other suitable mp), and then proceed to take it as far as possible with just picked up items in game (no shops other than for repair).  And just to make sure it doesn't go on forever, the run ends after act 1, fastest team to beat act 1 wins?

Comment: @spartacus Ironman! =) My favorite in Diablo 1.

Answer (score 1):

## Which game we play

People will donate for their favorite game, and we will marathon through the games in top to bottom order. For open ended games, we can choose to either set a goal or to marathon until something gets more money than that game.

Comment: Trouble is people donating for their favorite game, is going to work against the top tag marathon :p

Answer (score 1):

## For <del>Science</del> Answers

We can give them a mechanism (not on the site) to ask questions which we will test in the game. When a question gets enough donations, we hope onto that game and science an answer for them. If the question they want answered is already on the site, they can link to it.