# What games should we marathon and what should our goals be for each game? [Complete]

Tags: discussion, charity

**Voting for games has closed. Please visit [this meta question to suggest goals for each game](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6898/what-should-our-marathon-goals-be)**

This is going to be a lot easier to do in chat given the number of games. I've set up [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7451/charity-games) to use to discuss both what games we should play and what our goals should be for each game.

In the chat, please **star top tag games you want to see us marathon** and **reply to the game name to suggest a goal for that game**. At the end, I'll create a summary of everything here for reference.

Good games to vote for would be ones that:

- Are easy to stream
- Have obvious or good goals that can be set
- Are more popular (higher on the list is a more popular tag)
- One that you like and may be willing to play for the marathon

Comment: I think you  need to figure out the format of the marathon, more importantly. Are you going to have a bunch of different streamers share the same account, or jump around to different accounts, or is there some way for a central person to restream various different perspectives? Kind of important when you have to decide which games to play.

Comment: Are we picking people to play each game after we pick games or what? I could definitely stream for a few of the currently high-starred games. Also are we doing twitch or what?

Comment: @Decency I still need to look into Twitch and what is actually possible through that, but that is my current goal. I'd like to have a master account and turn on/off streams from certain people at given times.

Comment: @BenBrocka Yes, the goal will be to set the games, then see who can play what and in what timezones everyone is. I'll do sign-ups for everything once we get the list (which, from chat, it looks like we aren't too far away from).

Comment: Progress Quest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Voting has Finished

We have our list of games. They are:

- **Minecraft** (12 votes)
- **Portal 2** (10 votes)
- **Terraria** (8 votes)
- **Borderlands 2** (6 votes)

For 5th place, we have a 4-way tie. I'll be resolving this with my votes (since I couldn't vote). I'm picking one game, with one more as an optional extra stream event.

- <del>**Starcraft 2** (4 votes)</del> Removed. No one was signing up for it, so I'm pulling it from the list. We'll have enough to stream anyway.
- **Team Fortress 2** as a second stream feed if we have enough people (4 votes)

There were a few goals suggested, but we'll need some dedicated effort to decide on goals seeing as how we didn't get enough.

Comment: X-com and Zelda both had 4 votes aswell...

Answer (score 7):

### Minecraft

I'd propose a marathon run.  A singleplayer hardcore (or multiplayer hardcore) starting from spawn, and in the end defeating the Ender Dragon or the Wither.

Comment: Multiplayer, the more the better. I'm very happy to spend a little AWS credit on a beefy server for a few hours so that we can have a reliable, lag-free game.

Comment: Wouldn't that be fun? Better to have nonhardcore, so if you die, there's no worries, but starting from scratch and facing the enderdragon/wither in the end

Comment: I think picking a good survival seed (e.g. island in the middle of the ocean with one tree) would make things interesting.

Comment: Could choose a mod pack people play, like FTB, and then set goals based on donations for tech level accomplishments. Could run an UHC match... Could play an adventure map where we swap in new players when they die in Hardcore mode.

Comment: Hey Everyone, if you all could vote and contribute in the chat, it would help me out. I'm trying to keep it all in one place and not have too many answers here. I'll summarize everything here after a little while so that we can know what is being played and what the goals are.

Answer (score 1):

### Skyrim

Marathon run through the game based upon pledge level to include side quests or X amount of random quests. Could also include DLC storylines and accomplishments in the tiered progression... Biggest problem I forsee with this one is resisting the Oh Shiny! mentality so driven into the game.

Answer (score 1):

### Diablo 3

Similar to Skyrim, and another high profile tag on the site. Runs from scratch to finish could be done and include a group of players to go through with as many of them streaming as desired. Pledge levels could unlock accomplishment of challenges within the game or made up by the community as well as a certain level of progression through the game.

Comment: Hey James, thanks for the contribution, but would you mind posting this in the chat linked in the question? Just makes it easier to keep it all in one spot for me to summarize later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Borderlands 2

We could do some boss runs, especially raid bosses. We'd want to practice first, but I can volunteer a healing Siren for any main game/DLC raid boss. Optional killing methods include no cheap tactics (the bee, evil smasher exploit) or wacky killing methods (only certain types of guns or something silly).

Other BL2 ideas?

Comment: Why not play a play through on different difficulty levels? People will be watching to be entertained and .. well this game has a fairly entertaining story :)

Comment: @James it's also a rather long story, I'm not sure how well that would work. A glitch-free speedrun would still probably take several hours...

Comment: We are talking about a gaming marathon here, not a gaming sprint :D Heck I am considering a Skyrim Marathon afterall

Comment: Unless the marathon is literally multiple days I just don't see anyone completing a playthrough from start to finish

Comment: For wacky killing methods, sniper riffles only for 4 anarchy mechromancers