# What should our marathon goals be?

Tags: discussion, charity

We need to pick donation goals for each of our charity games. Please create answers with the following format:

```
# Game Name

 * Easiest Goal
 * Slightly Harder Goal
 * Harder Goal
 * Hardest Goal
```

Suggest as many goals as you want to in a single post. 1 is fine, but more is preferred if you have more ideas. Vote on goals you'd like to see. If the goals need more information or context, be sure to include that.

Feel free to add/remove/discuss things in comments for each post.

**NOTE:** Because we have 5 games and we'll be trying to do this in a (globally spanning) weekend, please make the goals are achievable in a time sensitive manner. Goals that would take a week to complete aren't good goals. We can have multiple streams going at once, but I'd like to limit it to 2 at a time if we can.

### [Sign up for the games you want to play](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6900/sign-ups-for-marathon-gaming)

## Marathon Games

- **Minecraft**
- **Portal 2**
- **Terraria**
- **Borderlands 2**

Comment: Honestly I think it'd make more sense to _first_ identify who's going to run and _then_ decide the goals with them.

Comment: @badp I'd considered doing it that way, but I kind of thought it might make more sense if you knew what you were signing up for. But I'll start sign up for the games now, since I think people would like to start putting their name in anyway

Answer (score 2):

## Terraria

Well, we have to keep playing if we expect people to keep watching and donating.  Therefore, things crucial to game progression should be goals from the start.  The overall goal being to defeat each of the three Hardmode bosses.  Donation goals should set interesting restrictions on *how* we play the game.

- Only allow X chests for storage.  Everything else must be destroyed or sold.
- Every Y amount donated, we have to destroy the contents of a random chest.
- Play in Hardmode without a safety barrier.

Now obviously these can't be all the goals.  Instead of spelling out an entire donation breakdown, let's just use this answer to suggest goals that fit the *theme* of this idea.

Comment: Oh gods... Those are brutal! D=

Comment: I don't think a safety barrier (I assume you mean a barrier that doesn't let hallows or the corruption through) would be that important in a game that will last a dozen hours or so. Also, there's nothing quite like watching somebody manage their inventory/agonizing over what items to keep.

Comment: A low level donation a random chest or one the players pick. A high level donation, the donor gets to pick the chest.

Comment: They'd have to be pretty high donations for destroying entire chests. I don't know about you, but I don't normally have very many chests when I play, less than 20.

Answer (score 1):

## Minecraft

- Marathon run: 42195m (blocks) in a specified direction (time: about 2 hours on boat if it's mostly water)
- ... not using boats, but getting pig-riding equipment, beds and possibly two or three Ender Pearls at the start; swimming is fine (time: about 3 hours)
- ... without the equipment (time: heavily dependent on the terrain, but not under 3 hours)
- ... and not allowed to use self-crafted beds either (time: same as above, but if you die late in the race, you can pretty much give up)

You might want to restrict PvP on this one ...

Since the latter goals would require to have a mostly continuous terrain in one direction, the seed for the world would need to be pre-checked by whoever sets up the server using AMIDST or similar tools. For some easier planning for the run, the (rough) map of the world could be provided prior to the race using the same tool.

As an additional rule, I'd restrict people from going through the Nether - not so much because it would be unfairly faster, but because it would split the participants in the race too much from each other.

Comment: If no self-crafted beds, then how about pre-built checkpoints? Every 7500m or what have you?

Comment: How would we receive materials? Would they be given or would we have to find them?

Comment: @jeffreylin_: You can always mine and gather materials as usual (and it would be probably wise to grab a bunch of wood and stone and make stone tools at the beginning). Same for food: The race is long enough that you'll *have* to stop and get some, either by raiding a village or killing mobs; but if all you have is raw flesh, do you stop and cook it first? The idea is that people have to balance the time spent gathering resources with the goals of the race. In the easier modes, the resources are either given at start, or the race is going over water, which has minimal requirements.

Comment: @Slurpee: It's a possibility, though the last mode is *supposed* to be hard. The checkpoint still present the problem that you have to be there at night for them to work, so they'd need to be within half a (Minecraftian) day's walking distance from each other to minimise boring waiting time (something like 2000m).

Comment: Every $x donated, someone has to spin a random selector which either lets them pick up a weapon/equipment, or drop it....

Comment: @djsmiley2k: ... or you could simply allow people to "donate" equipment (armour, weapons, food, beds, materials, Ender Pearls) to people of their choice - with the restriction that they aren't the leaders at this moment. I don't know what exact format the whole thing will have, so no idea how do-able it would be.

Answer (score 1):

## Terraria

Overall Goals:

- Defeat the Wall of Flesh
- Defeat The Twins/The Destroyer/Skeletron Prime
- Craft full Hallowed Armor

Donation Goals:

- Summon a boss, right then and there, and fight it

Answer (score 0):

## Portal 2

I think it would be fun here to do a co-op race with teams trying to complete co-op first.

- Every *X* dollars, all the teams have to high-five before they can continue the puzzle
- Puzzles can only be completed by going into a blue portal, and out of an orange
- 1 Player can only move via portals
- A death requires a restart of the test

Answer (score 0):

### Borderlands 2

Overall goals:

- TVHM all bosses run (as in just bosses, playing in an already completed game)
- DLC 1-3 story quest
- DLC 1-3 side quest run
- Main quest minimal playthrough

Specific donation reward ideas:

- Pay to force a player to respec into a specific tree
- Force a player to use certain gun types/elements/brands

Complications:

Borderlands 2 is a long game, ~20 hours for main quest completion. That time can probably be cut down significantly, but I have no idea how much, especially without cheating with a level 50 co op partner. The DLC is also a complication, everyone doing a DLC run would have to own the DLC (I have it, personally though).

All bosses probably wouldn't take all that long, but it might end up being too short. Having trouble thinking of the happy medium, I think DLCs are the best option for that, each can be completed in  <5 hours as a first playthrough, even faster if we know what we're doing.

---

Any other suggestions? Leave a comment or add a bullet point.

Comment: You need to ensure that Axton's speedglitch can't be used, nobody can use Evil Smashers (glitch)

Comment: No exploits is probably a given, unless we're planning to do a a proper, minimum time speedrun. And I'm not aware of a way to actually shave off enough time in BL2 to make that kind of speedrun worth it

Comment: Besides, speedruns ain't something you can improvise, unless we want to become the laughing stock of the internet :P

Comment: DLC runs would be a lot of fun, and wouldn't take too long.