# Sign-ups for Marathon gaming

Tags: discussion, charity

Alright, let's start sign-ups for our charity games. Please comment on the game you'd want to play for our marathon. Also, **please include your timezone** (e.g. GMT-8 for me, for Pacific Time zone, US). Date is still TBD, but we will coordinate with everyone when we start deciding that and try to pick a date that works best for as many people as possible.

Comment: I'm thinking out of all these 5 games, minecraft will be the only one that is going to pull views on twitch tho.

Answer (score 3):

## Minecraft

Assuming our goal is something feasible like defeat the ender dragon, or even wither. I (@fredley) don't think perma-death is a great idea, as it would make things pretty tedious if we get nowhere at all.

Donation goals suggestions:

- No armour allowed
- Only iron weapons/tools allowed
- Start on a remote island with no/few trees (I think we should do this anyway!)
- [Suggest More](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6898/what-should-our-marathon-goals-be)

Comment: I would like to play. GMT.

Comment: Sure enough, I'd like to join. UTC+1 right now.

Comment: Sign me up! UTC

Comment: I might be there, depending on how my day goes. New York time (GMT -5)

Comment: Count me in! I would also be able to host a server.  GMT -5

Comment: This looks like we could have a hand over from the GMT-5 guys to the GMT guys, which would be cool.

Comment: @fredley Tag team this marathon.

Comment: Be sure to get some anti hacks, because some people like Nodus and the like.

Comment: It has been a while but can play, i'm at GMT+1

Comment: @MartinSojka Can you send an email to andrew.hushbeck@imgineme.com with your Arqade username so that we can start coordinating?

Answer (score 2):

## Borderlands 2

Donation goals suggestions:

- None. [Suggest some](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6898/what-should-our-marathon-goals-be)

Comment: Consider me _tentatively_ in for this. I do _not_ own the DLC

Comment: I can do this one for sure. GMT-6 (Central US)

Comment: I'll see what I can do.  Midterms are coming up soon though; if there's a concrete date you guys are doing this, please let me know. Whatever'sontheeastcoast time -5 (atlantic or something)

Comment: Assuming I'm free that weekend I should be able to help with this. GMT -5 (Eastern US). I've got a season pass, so I've got all the DLC (and will have the next one if it's out before the marathon)

Comment: Depending on when this takes place, I may be up for this. I have all the DLC and I'm GMT-6

Comment: Depending on how (and when) we do this I would be interested.  I bought the season pass, so I have all the DLC, but I currently do not have a level 50 character. UTC-4

Comment: @Retrosaur The actual marathon won't happen before May or something.

Comment: I would do this.  GMT -5

Comment: @Retrosaur If you are still interested, can you send an email to andrew.hushbeck@imgineme.com with your Arqade username so that we can start coordinating?

Comment: Will do, many thanks

Comment: GMT-5.  All DLC.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Could you also send me an email with your Arqade username?

Answer (score 1):

## Terraria

Donation goals suggestions:

- None. [Suggest some](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6898/what-should-our-marathon-goals-be)

Comment: Tentatively in for this one if there's extra time/whatever. BL2 takes priority though. GMT-6 (Central US)

Comment: I'd be interested in this one, if we get a few more people.

Comment: Haven't played I a while, but why not. UTC

Comment: Could be fun, i'm at gmt+1

Comment: @Lyrion Can you send an email to andrew.hushbeck@imgineme.com with your Arqade username so that we can start coordinating?

Answer (score 0):

## Portal 2

Donation goals suggestions:

- *(Co-op race)* Every X dollars, all the teams have to high-five before they can continue the puzzle
- *(Co-op race)* Puzzles can only be completed by going into a blue portal, and out of an orange
- *(Co-op race)* 1 Player can only move via portals
- *(Co-op race)* A death requires a restart of the test
- [Suggest more](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6898/what-should-our-marathon-goals-be)

Comment: I'd love to play this one. GMT-8, Pacific Time US

Comment: I'd be up for this one tentatively but BL2 will probably be a long one. I'd rather do BL2 than Portal GMT-6 (Central US)

Comment: Much like @BenBrocka, I'd be able to do this, but would prefer BL2. GMT-5 (Eastern US)